# Why do glBindRenderbuffer and glRenderbufferStorage each take a "target" parameter?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

> It takes a target parameter, but the only viable target is
>   GL_RENDERBUFFER​.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindRenderbuffer.xml

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlRenderbufferStorage

(I'm just learning OpenGL, and already found these two today; maybe I can expect this seemingly-useless target parameter to be common in many functions?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is bit of the rationale behind the `target` parameter in the issue 30 of the original [`EXT_framebuffer_object`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt) extension specification. (I generally recommend people to read the relevant extensions specs even for features which have become core GL features, since those specs have often more details, and sometimes contain bits of reasoning of the ARB (or vendors) for doing things one way or the other, especially in the "issues" section.):

> (30) Do the calls to deal with renderbuffers need a target
>            parameter?  It seems unlikely this will be used for anything.
>
> RESOLUTION: resolved, yes
>
> Whether we call it a "target" or not, there is *some* piece
>   of state in the context to hold the current renderbuffer
>   binding.  This is required so that we can call routines like
>   RenderbufferStorage and {Get}RenderbufferParameter() without
>   passing in an object name.  It is also possible we may
>   decide to use the renderbuffer target parameter to
>   distinguish between multisample and non multisample buffers.
>   Given those reasons, the precedent of texture objects, and
>   the possibility we may come up with some other renderbuffer
>   target types in the future, it seems prudent and not all
>   that costly to just include the target type now.

Answer (score 4):

It's frequently the case that core OpenGL only defines one legal value for certain parameters, but extensions add others.  Whether or not there are any more values defined in extensions today, clearly the architects wanted to leave that door open to future extensions.

Comment: It would be nice if documentation would provide examples of this happening; do you know of a resource that lists when this has happened, or at least remember a case, yourself?

Comment: @Jessy: `glBindBuffer (...)` is probably the number one example of this sort of thing happening. Buffer Objects are among the busiest part of the OpenGL API (in terms of new ones being invented). Originally, when `GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object` introduced that part of the API there were only 2 binding points `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Now, there are dozens of different binding points for different kinds of buffers, (*e.g.* Shader Storage, Uniform, Texture, Feedback, Pixel(Transfer), Copy, etc.).

Comment: @Jessy: Though that might not be the best analogy; Buffer Objects have no explicit type, their role is implied from where you bind them. You can use the same Buffer Object as a vertex buffer or a uniform buffer simply by binding it somewhere different. But you get the general idea here, when VBOs were introduced there was a single `glBindBuffer (...)` function to serve only 2 binding points rather than 2 separate binding functions. This makes expanding the API *much* simpler.

Comment: All of what you guys have said is useful, but doesn't answer the question for someone who knows only what I know now. To me, it seems that part of the answer is, "because C doesn't support function overloading", which I didn't know until yesterday either.

Comment: @Jessy: For example, [`GL_ARB_depth_texture`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/depth_texture.txt) adds new values that can be passed to the existing functions `TexImage1D`, `TexImage2D`,
`CopyTexImage1D`, `CopyTexImage2D`, `GetTexImage`, `TexImage1D`,
`TexImage2D`, `TexSubImage1D`, and `TexSubImage2D`

Comment: Good enough; thanks. You'd think that a document that's so important for pretty graphics would be more readable. I'm disgusted but appreciative.